# Is the Cennini's Libro dell'arte part of public domain?

Tags: oil-paint

I was wondering if this book is in the public domain (the French translation by Victor Mortez) : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libro_dell%27arte.

I suppose the book in italian is, but I'm not shure for the translation...

Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi! This is not really a question that fits this website: while it is about a (very important) book about the practical side of painting, the question whether it is in the public domain is one about law and copyright.

Comment: Do note that Victor *Mottez* lived in the 19th century, and his translation seems to stem from [1858](https://archive.org/details/traitedelapeintu00cenn), which means the work is over 160 years old. I'm not sure about French law, but works that old usually are in the public domain.

Comment: Thank you I'll try on another forum !